# usage of hyphen and en-dash

Tags: punctuation, hyphens

It is common to use an en-dash when we use same or opposite term such as cell–cell, Iran–Saudi Arabia, etc.

My question is: "Can we use an en-dash for **Iran–Gulf**?"

We all know that the Gulf is not a country.

Comment: This is almost certainly not correct, but could you give your usage example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, a hyphen is not an en-dash. The *basic* rules are as follows (but check the links below for details):

- The hyphen is used for compound words. Examples: re-read, pro-American. (But there are a number of cases where the en-dash is used instead.)
- The en-dash is used in, for example, the following cases:
- In a range of numbers. For example: [1904–05 in Belgian football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1904%E2%80%9305_in_Belgian_football).
- To describe certain relationships or connections. For example: [cell–cell interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell%E2%80%93cell_interaction).
- For geographic connections or relationships. For example: [Iran–Saudi Arabia relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93Saudi_Arabia_relations).

Without context, it is not entirely clear what "Iran–Gulf" refers to. The [Persian Gulf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_Gulf), which is also known as the Gulf of Iran?

See also:

- The Punctuation Guide: [En dash](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html) and [Hyphen](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/hyphen.html).
- The Chicago Manual of Style Online: [Hyphens, En Dashes, Em Dashes](http://chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/HyphensEnDashesEmDashes/faq0002.html).
- Wikipedia: [Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash).
- [When should I use an em-dash, an en-dash, and a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2116/163363) on English Language & Usage Stack Exchange.
- Peter K Sheerin: [The Trouble With EM ’n EN (and Other Shady Characters)](http://alistapart.com/article/emen/), *A List Apart* 19 October 2001. (This is aimed at web developers.)